# Mutable objects don't change when passed as arguments in a function

Tags: python

I don't really understand why the values of these objects don't change after the call of the function.I have previously read on a site that mutable objects can be passed as arguments , and their value can be changed.

```
def concatenare(Q, sigma, s, F, delta):
    Q = Q1.union(Q2R)
    sigma = sigma1.union(sigma2)
    s = s1.copy()
    F = set(F2)
    delta = delta1.copy()
    delta.update(delta2R)
    for finale in F1:
        delta[(finale, s2R[0])] = '.'

Q = set()
F = set()
sigma = set()
delta = dict()
cuvinte = list()
s = list()

concatenare(Q, sigma, s, F, delta)


# Q1,Q2R,sigma1,sigma2,F2,delta1,delta2r,F1 are previously defined and have some values assigned
```

```
output:
set()
set()
{}
[]
set()
```

Comment: You don't mutate any of the arguments. You explicitly make copies of them then mutate the copies. What is your intent? Maybe you should return the copies? Or not make copies and mutate the arguments?

Comment: That code throws a bunch of NameErrors.

Comment: But how should I do in order to mutate those objects ?

Comment: Their values can be mutated in the function, but any assignments will be lost.

Comment: Should I iterate through all these objects and add/append the elements in order to be saved after the function call ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't using the values passed in, only assigning over them, you should have your function return all the values you want:

```
def concatenare():
    Q = Q1.union(Q2R)
    sigma = sigma1.union(sigma2)
    s = s1.copy()
    F = set(F2)
    delta = delta1.copy()
    delta.update(delta2R)
    for finale in F1:
        delta[(finale, s2R[0])] = '.'
    return Q, sigma, s, F, delta

Q, sigma, s, F, delta = concatenare()
```

Or, (heresy!) assign to globals, since you are using globals to build the values anyway.

Comment: Thank you!It works.Does the problem I have encountered resides in the fact that all variables in python are a reference to a particular memory address ?

Comment: This has all the details you need: [Facts and Myths about Python Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)